# Find number pattern in string and remove it

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove a pattern from a string, I think regex could do the job, but I'm having trouble solving this.

The pattern must be in the end of the string.

```
string fileName = "File (123)";
string pattern = " (0)";
string cleanName = PatternRemover(fileName, pattern);
//Should result in: cleanName == "File"
```

Edit:
Ok, here is the code that I'm using now after your answers:

```
    public static string GetNextFilePath2(string fullPath, ref uint id, string idFormat)
    {
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
        string fileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath);
        if (ext.Length > 0 && ext[0] != '.')
            ext = "." + ext;

        string baseName = Regex.Replace(fileNameNoExt, @"\s\(\d+\)", "");

        string fileName = baseName + " (" + id.ToString(idFormat) + ")" + ext;
        string path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
        while (File.Exists(path))
        {
            id++;
            fileName = baseName + " (" + id.ToString(idFormat) + ")" + ext;
            path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);
        }
        return path;
    }
```

It works, but:

1. It always start to count from id, I think it may be better to start
   from the file name number.
2. I was hopping to use something like "(0)" as a method parameter that would indicate the pattern to be removed and also the "(" would be parametrized. I'm doing it "manually" now on this line: string fileName = baseName + " (" + id.ToString(idFormat) + ")" + ext;

Comment: What is your pattern exactly?

Comment: What's the pattern you want to remove - is it `(\d+)`? Can it appear anywhere in the input string?

Comment: Your comment shows `cleanName == "File"`; what happens to the `.jpg` extension in the original text?

Comment: @SonerGönül, my pattern is "(numbers)". Lee, yes it can, but I want to remove only the ones at the end of the string. newfurniturey, I edited the question, ".jpg" is not relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex:

```
var subject = "File (123).jpg";
var fileNameWithExtension = Regex.Replace(subject,@"\s*\(\d+\)","");
var fileNameWithoutPath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameWithExtension);
```

And thanks for @habib, I'd not have come with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` in this for stripping the extension.

Comment: Thanks, I have just edited the question. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: @Pedro77 You can use this code to retrieve id. `var id= Regex.Match(subject,@"\s*\((?<number>\d+)\)").Groups["number"].Value;`

Answer (score 6):

You can do that without REGEX like:

```
string newFileName = new String(fileName
                               .Where(r => !char.IsDigit(r)
                                           && r != '('
                                           && r != ')'
                                           && r != ' ').ToArray());
```

This would give you `File.jpg`

If you only want to get the file name then you can use:

```
string fileNameWithoutPath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFileName);
// it would give you `File`
```

Comment: @gleng, its not quick :) it is after 6 minutes of question :)

Comment: but your comment is so quick habib ;)

Comment: Thank you for the alternate solution without regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
\s\(\d+\)\.jpg
```

assuming you do actually want the extension removed and the extension is always ".jpg". Otherwise:

```
\s\(\d+\)
```

Looks for a set of digits in brackets proceeded by a space.